# Implementation details for PACK and UNPACK

Tags: michelson

In the [Operations on bytes](http://tezos.gitlab.io/master/whitedoc/michelson.html#operations-on-bytes) section of the Michelson white document, it is mentioned that:

> "PACK: Serializes a piece of data to its optimized binary representation."

I am curious to know more details of how `PACK` and `UNPACK` are implemented and what the binary representation is. I have looked through the source code and there are not any many comments in the implementation.

Edit:

The details that user catsigma have given are very useful, but I would still like to be able to follow how serialization works in the source code and where the operation to binary code mappings come from.

I found the `interp` function here and the implementation of `Pack`:

[src/proto_alpha/lib_protocol/src/script_interpreter.ml#L697](https://gitlab.com/tezos/tezos/blob/master/src/proto_alpha/lib_protocol/src/script_interpreter.ml#L697)

```
let rec interp =
...
| Pack t, Item (value, rest) ->
    Script_ir_translator.pack_data ctxt t value >>=? fun (bytes, ctxt) ->
    logged_return (Item (bytes, rest), ctxt)
```

`pack_data` is defined here:

[src/proto_alpha/lib_protocol/src/script_ir_translator.ml#L3162](https://gitlab.com/tezos/tezos/blob/master/src/proto_alpha/lib_protocol/src/script_ir_translator.ml#L3162)

```
let pack_data ctxt typ data =
  unparse_data ctxt Optimized typ data >>=? fun (data, ctxt) ->
  let unparsed = strip_annotations @@ data in
  let bytes = Data_encoding.Binary.to_bytes_exn expr_encoding (Micheline.strip_locations unparsed) in
  Lwt.return @@ Gas.consume ctxt (Script.serialized_cost bytes) >>=? fun ctxt ->
  let bytes = MBytes.concat "" [ MBytes.of_string "\005" ; bytes ] in
  Lwt.return @@ Gas.consume ctxt (Script.serialized_cost bytes) >>=? fun ctxt ->
  return (bytes, ctxt)
```

`Data_encoding.Binary.to_bytes_exn` looks like the key function.

[src/lib_data_encoding/binary_writer.ml#L338](https://gitlab.com/tezos/tezos/blob/master/src/lib_data_encoding/binary_writer.ml#L338)

```
let to_bytes_exn e v =
  match Encoding.classify e with
  | `Fixed n -> begin
      (* Preallocate the complete buffer *)
      let state = { buffer = MBytes.create n ;
                    offset = 0 ; allowed_bytes = Some n } in
      write_rec e state v ;
      state.buffer
    end
  | `Dynamic | `Variable ->
      (* Preallocate a minimal buffer and let's not hardcode a
         limit to its extension. *)
      let state = { buffer = MBytes.create 4096 ;
                    offset = 0 ; allowed_bytes = None } in
      write_rec e state v ;
      MBytes.sub state.buffer 0 state.offset
```

Now let's try to find what the encoding of `False` would be. Here is some more code reorganized [src/lib_data_encoding/binary_writer.ml](https://gitlab.com/tezos/tezos/blob/master/src/lib_data_encoding/binary_writer.ml):

```
let rec write_rec : type a. a Encoding.t -> state -> a -> unit =
  fun e state value ->
    let open Encoding in
    match e.encoding with
    | Bool -> Atom.bool state value
    ...

module Atom = struct
  let bool state v = uint8 state (if v then 255 else 0)
  let uint8 = int `Uint8
  let int kind state v =
    check_int_range (Binary_size.min_int kind) v (Binary_size.max_int kind) ;
    let ofs = state.offset in
    may_resize state (Binary_size.integer_to_size kind) ;
    set_int kind state.buffer ofs v

  let check_int_range min v max =
    if (v < min || max < v) then
      raise (Invalid_int { min ; v ; max })

  let set_int kind buffer ofs v =
    match kind with
    ...
    | `Uint8 -> MBytes.set_int8 buffer ofs v
end
```

Now we need to find `MBytes.set_int8`. I have only found the type signature file.

[src/lib_protocol_environment/sigs/v1/mBytes.mli](https://gitlab.com/tezos/tezos/blob/master/src/lib_protocol_environment/sigs/v1/mBytes.mli)

`mBytes` looks like it is an external library but I haven't found the name. Also, I am not seeing how this matches up with the `op_mapping` as mentioned in tezbridge-crypto.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I have implemented the `PACK` and `UNPACK` in `tezbridge-crypto` project.

You can checkout the source code here:
[codec.js#L426](https://github.com/tezbridge/tezbridge-crypto/blob/master/src/PsddFKi3/codec.js#L426)

Here are some test cases:
[index.js#L35](https://github.com/tezbridge/tezbridge-crypto/blob/master/test/index.js#L35)

In short words, there are several mappings([codec.js#L166](https://github.com/tezbridge/tezbridge-crypto/blob/master/src/PsddFKi3/codec.js#L166), [codec.js#L288](https://github.com/tezbridge/tezbridge-crypto/blob/master/src/PsddFKi3/codec.js#L288)) between the Michline value and the binary representation.
The conversion is just a one way walk though the data, and each data type(like `int`, `string`..) has its specific encoding/decoding method.

Comment: I was grepping around the source code from the [tezos](https://gitlab.com/tezos/tezos) repository for the op_mapping you have. I am curious where these mappings are defined in there, but I have not found them. Looking through tezos source code has led me to a function `write_rec` in `binary_writer.ml`.

Comment: These are also good resources: [The data_encoding library](http://tezos.gitlab.io/mainnet/tutorials/data_encoding.html) and [Module Tezos_data_encoding.Data_encoding](http://tezos.gitlab.io/mainnet/api/api-inline.html#tezos-data-encoding/Tezos_data_encoding/index.html)