# What's the best way to convert from TMutez to TBytes?

Tags: smart-contracts, michelson, smartpy, types

[Previously when I asked about converting types](https://tezos.stackexchange.com/questions/2919/is-it-possible-to-convert-types-in-smartpy/2920#2920), I got this useful suggestion:

> For mutez, you could start to convert to int (by dividing by 1 mutez) and then use the same techniques.

I'm wondering if there are any similar tricks specifically to go from mutez to bytes, or int to bytes. Ideally tricks for doing so that can be done in SmartPy.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `sp.pack` on expressions of most regular types. It computes a serialized representation of your data.

Comment: Ah okay great. This almost works except would it be possible to have the number be in hex representation? e.g. converting 255 into 0xFF? Right now using ```pack``` on 255 I get 0x0500bf03

Comment: or if not, is there documentation to describe the steps to get to the serialization?

Comment: There is this other question dealing with the format. https://tezos.stackexchange.com/questions/612/implementation-details-for-pack-and-unpack. 
I don't think there is a way to get `0xFF` from 255 without coding it in exactly the same way you can code pretty-printers.